Finding the positions of a search string within an input string
I am trying to print out the positions of a search string within an input string. However, my code only takes the input and search string and does nothing else:
section .data
    ; Define the maximum length of the search string
    MAX_SEARCH_LENGTH equ 1000

section .bss
    ; Define variables
    SEARCH_KEY resb MAX_SEARCH_LENGTH
    INPUT resb MAX_SEARCH_LENGTH
    index_counter resd 1
    index_counter1 resd 1
    temp resd 1

section .text
    global main

main:
    ; Read the search string
    mov eax, 0       ; sys_read syscall number
    mov edi, 0       ; file descriptor 0 (stdin)
    mov esi, SEARCH_KEY
    mov edx, MAX_SEARCH_LENGTH
    syscall

    ; Check if search string contains a newline
    mov ecx, SEARCH_KEY
    mov ebx, 0       ; counter
check_newline_loop:
    cmp byte [ecx + ebx], 10  ; newline character
    je found_newline
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx, MAX_SEARCH_LENGTH
    jl check_newline_loop
    ; If no newline found, print error message and exit
    mov eax, 1       ; sys_write syscall number
    mov edi, 1       ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    mov esi, error_message
    mov edx, error_message_length
    syscall
    jmp exit

found_newline:
    ; Read the input data
    mov eax, 0       ; sys_read syscall number
    mov edi, 0      ; file descriptor 0 (stdin)
    mov esi, INPUT
    mov edx, MAX_SEARCH_LENGTH
    syscall

    ; Set up index_counter for comparison
    xor eax, eax
    mov [index_counter], eax

compare_first:
    ; Compare characters
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, [index_counter]
    mov bl, byte [INPUT + eax]
    cmp bl, 0
    je exit
    cmp bl, byte [SEARCH_KEY]
    je set_index
    inc dword [index_counter]
    jmp compare_first

set_index:
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, 0
    mov [index_counter1], eax
    jmp next_characters

next_characters:
    mov eax, [index_counter1]
    add eax, 1
    mov [index_counter1], eax

    mov bl, byte [SEARCH_KEY + eax]
    cmp bl, 0
    je print_index

    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, [index_counter]
    add eax, [index_counter1]
    mov [temp], eax
    mov bl, byte [INPUT + eax]
    cmp bl, 0
    je exit

    mov ecx, [index_counter1]
    mov eax, [temp]
    mov bl, byte [SEARCH_KEY + ecx]
    cmp bl, byte [INPUT + eax]
    je next_characters
    jmp increase_counter

increase_counter:
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, [index_counter]
    inc dword [index_counter]
    jmp compare_first

print_index:
    ; Print the index
    mov eax, 1       ; sys_write syscall number
    mov edi, 1       ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    mov esi, [temp]
    add esi, 48      ; convert index to ASCII
    add esi, 0x30
    mov edx, 1
    syscall
    jmp next_characters

exit:
    ; Exit the program
    mov eax, 60      ; sys_exit syscall number
    xor edi, edi     ; exit code 0
    syscall

section .data
    error_message db "Error: Search string not found.", 0xA
    error_message_length equ $ - error_message
    searchString db "Enter search string: ", 10, 0
    inputString db "Enter input string: ", 10, 0

I inputted in:
o
hello world.

I was expecting after the input:
o
hello world.
found at postion: 4
found at postion: 7


Obviously the found at position string isn't even in your code so don't expect that to be printed. As for the number, your print_index is doing the ascii conversion twice and it is not passing the address to write. Try add byte [temp], 48; mov esi, temp (notice no []).

I updated the code using the instructions you gave, but it still only takes input and then terminates the code.
